# Connecting to Fauxton via web

Tags: amazon-ec2, couchdb

I am running a couchdb from an Amazon ec2 instance (Ubuntu Bionic) and using an elastic IP. I'm able to SSH into the instance via PuTTy, but I am unable to access Fauxton from the web using http://(myip)/_utils. I'm just getting a "refused to connect" error.

I just spun up this ec2 instance, as I'm trying to upgrade from an old instance. I have another ec2 instance up, and both are using the same security group. That security group is tied to a VPC that both are using. Could this be part of the problem? Both ec2's have separate elastic IPs.

I expect to access Fauxton, but am instead getting ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

Comment: Probably you already checked any possible firewall and closed ports, right?